# How do I make a categorical variable on x-axis of ggplot geom_line with multiple groups

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

I'm starting with

```r
>df57 <- data.frame(cellType = c("4.57", "4.57", "8.57", "8.57", "8.28.57", "8.28.57"), 
                        ORR = c("PD", "nonPD"),
                        BL = rep(0, each=6), 
                        Treated = c(10, -5, 8, -4, 15, -2))
>df57melt <- melt(df57)
>df57melt

cellType    ORR variable  value
1   4.57    PD      BL      0
2   4.57    nonPD   BL      0
3   8.57    PD      BL      0
4   8.57    nonPD   BL      0
5   8.28.57 PD      BL      0
6   8.28.57 nonPD   BL      0
7   4.57    PD      Treated 10
8   4.57    nonPD   Treated -5
9   8.57    PD      Treated 8
10  8.57    nonPD   Treated -4
11  8.28.57 PD      Treated 15
12  8.28.57 nonPD   Treated -2
```

I want to make a line plot in which treatment is on the x-axis (BL, Treated) and value on the y-axis (continuous). I want to have three cell types (4.57, 8.57, and 8.28.57; I want coded by line color) that each have response variable (PD and nonPD; I want coded by line style).

I plot what I think should work:

```r
>ggplot(data=df57melt, aes(x=variable, y = value)) + 
  geom_line(aes(linetype = ORR, color = cellType))

geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?

#so I add group info
>ggplot(data=df57melt, aes(x=variable, y = value, group = cellType)) + 
  geom_line(aes(linetype = ORR, color = cellType))

Error: geom_path: If you are using dotted or dashed lines, colour, size and linetype must be constant over the line

#but if I change from categorical x to continuous x...
>ggplot(data=df57melt, aes(x=as.numeric(variable), y = value)) + 
  geom_line(aes(linetype = ORR, color = cellType))
```

And it gives me something like what I want...but not quite 
[image: Line plot]
How do I get it to recognize my x as categorical?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `group` aesthetic to tell ggplot which combinations of columns to treat as separate groups. `ggplot` will draw lines between all points within a given group.

By default, with a categorical x-axis, ggplot will treat each x value as a separate group. In this case, the data end up grouped by `variable`, `ORR`, and `cellType`, resulting in only one value per group. We can override that by setting the `group` aesthetic. We want a separate line for each unique combination of `ORR` and `cellType`, so we use `interaction(ORR, cellType)` to group by each combination of these two variables.

In the code below, I've also used `gather` from the `tidyr` package to convert the data frame to long format, since `reshape2` is an older package that is no longer under active development.

```
library(tidyverse)
theme_set(theme_classic())

df57 %>% 
  gather(key, value, BL:Treated) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=key, y=value)) + 
    geom_line(aes(linetype = ORR, color = cellType, 
                  group=interaction(ORR, cellType))) +
    scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0.05, 0.05))
```

[image]

What about something like this as an alternative:

```
df57 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=cellType, Treated, colour=ORR)) + 
    geom_hline(yintercept=0, colour="grey50", size=0.5) +
    geom_text(aes(label=sprintf("%1.1f", Treated))) +
    geom_text(data=. %>% 
                arrange(cellType) %>%
                group_by(ORR) %>% 
                slice(1) %>% 
                mutate(Treated=0.5*Treated),
              aes(label=gsub("nP", "n-P", ORR), x=0.65), hjust=1, fontface="bold") +
    geom_segment(aes(xend=cellType, yend=BL), linetype="11", size=0.3) +
    labs(x="Cell Type", y="Treatment Effect") +
    scale_x_discrete(expand=expand_scale(add=c(1,0.25))) + 
    guides(colour=FALSE) + 
    theme_classic(base_size=15)
```

[image]

If `PD` and `nonPD` can both be positive (or both negative) then you could do something like this:

```
df57 <- data.frame(cellType = c("4.57", "4.57", "8.57", "8.57", "8.28.57", "8.28.57"), 
                   ORR = c("PD", "nonPD"),
                   BL = rep(0, each=6), 
                   Treated = c(10, 5, 8, 4, 15, -2))

pd=position_dodge(0.5)
df57 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=cellType, Treated, colour=ORR)) + 
    geom_hline(yintercept=0, colour="grey50", size=0.5) +
    geom_text(aes(label=sprintf("%1.1f", Treated)), 
              position=pd, show.legend=FALSE) +
    geom_linerange(aes(ymin=BL, ymax=Treated), 
                 linetype="11", size=0.3, position=pd) +
    labs(x="Cell Type", y="Treatment Effect") +
    theme_classic(base_size=15) +
    theme(legend.position="bottom",
          legend.margin=margin(t=-5)) +
    scale_x_discrete(expand=expand_scale(add=c(0.3,0.3))) +
    guides(colour=guide_legend(override.aes=list(linetype="solid", size=4)))
```

[image]

And you can also of course reverse the roles of `ORR` and `cellType`:

```
df57 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=ORR, Treated, colour=cellType)) + 
    geom_hline(yintercept=0, colour="grey50", size=0.5) +
    geom_text(aes(label=sprintf("%1.1f", Treated)), 
              position=pd, show.legend=FALSE) +
    geom_linerange(aes(ymin=BL, ymax=Treated), 
                   linetype="11", size=0.3, position=pd) +
    labs(x="ORR", y="Treatment Effect") +
    theme_classic(base_size=15) +
    theme(legend.position="bottom",
          legend.margin=margin(t=-5)) +
    scale_x_discrete(expand=expand_scale(add=c(0.3,0.3))) +
    guides(colour=guide_legend(override.aes=list(linetype="solid", size=4)))
```

[image]

Comment: Your first answer is EXACTLY what I want. Thanks!
Your second answer, while beautiful, won't work because the "non-PD" results aren't always negative. If they are positive, then it would really throw off the aesthetic.

Comment: I've updated my answer to address the case where `PD` and `nonPD` can both be positive.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not really the answer, but I feel that you are trying to force the line where it is not supposed to be. I would propose:

```
ggplot(data=df57melt) + 
  geom_col(aes(x=as.factor(variable), 
               y = value,fill = as.factor(cellType),
               color = ORR,
               group=cellType),
           position = position_dodge(),size = 2)+
  scale_fill_grey()
```

[image]

Comment: I agree. I'd originally plotted the individual replicates as a dotplot, which I think is much more data-rich. My boss, however, wants the line because he feels it is more intuitive for the people he's presenting to. So is forcing the line impossible? I've seen others with categorical variables on their x-axis...